# Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS constantly crashing in multiple Mini Pc Asus Amd Ryzen 7 4700u

Tags: ubuntu, crash, asus

I have been using Mini Pc Asus Amd Ryzen 7 4700u with different configurations that range from 32gb memory to 64gb and 500gb SSD disk to 1Tb.

Crash details: it completely freezes, then a black screen for 1/2 seconds and then freeze again. It doesn't respond to keyboard and mouse.

Additional data:

- If I use WhatsApp desktop (any version) it crashes very fast
- Having more tabs open make it crash faster
- A computer with hardware encryption crashes much faster
- Syslog: https://pastebin.com/4E8VxP8f

Any insights?

Thanks!

Comment: Done syslog after crash

Comment: These logs are just before the crash

Comment: Added more logs before the crash. The crash was 12:40

Comment: Yea, I noticed as started looking even tho' you said "after crash"... your GPU is resetting, and it doesn't always recover. [Here's](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/2220) a freedesktop gitlab thread about similar behavior.

Comment: I think you bumped into [this kernel.org bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1995956).

Comment: It doesn't look as the kernel bug because it freezes, then a black screen for 1 second and then freezes again forever. The kernel bug stays in black.

Comment: Can I run another kernel to test it?

Comment: My kernel is 5.19.0-38-generic but if 6.x doesn't fix it I should wait. One of the computers without disk encryption runs well if I don't open WhatsApp but the other crashes all the time. I really don't know what to do at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the log, it looks like a GPU issue;
here is **[1]** a more close-fitting and mostly **already triaged** bug report.

Upgrade your kernel (see latest comment, still here **[1]**).

---

**[1]** https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/2113

Comment: It worked for my unencrypted computer but it doesn't work for the encrypted one, it throws an error at boot time

Comment: Disabling secure boot did the trick for the encrypted disk. If you know how to enable it, I would solve the whole things.

Comment: I think they are distinct issues; anyway, did you upgraded BIOS/firmware to latest version?

Comment: yes, but there is a problem changing the Kernel version and secure boot.

Comment: @PaulExchange explain better the above-mention 'problem'; add further info in OP

Comment: This is what happened: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1420339/custom-kernel-bad-shim-signature